# Message Text in Azure Queue is encoded, how do I remove this encoding?

Tags: c#, .net-standard, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues

When I add something to the queue, messageText becomes encoded, how do i remove it so that it is in clear text?

See the message text in the queue here

[image]

```
var queueClient = new QueueClient(ConnectionString, "paymentfiles2");
var r = await QueueClient.SendMessageAsync("Demo")
```

I use Azure.Storage.Queues, Version=12.4.2.0 in .NET Standard 2.0 project

Comment: I think that's an issue in Azure portal which does not show text correctly unless message body is base64 encoded. Use [Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to view.

Comment: In the Azure Storage Explorer there is an option to view/add with encoding (UTF8 or Base 64), but that option is not in QueueClient (Azure.Storage.Queues).

Comment: And if I add the message to the queue with the old WindowsAzure.Storage <https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/> then MessageText will be displayed correctly in Azure portal and Azure Storage Explorer

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `QueueClient.SendMessageAsync` sends the text in UTF8 encoding. But Azure portal assumes it as Base64, that's why it shows like garbage value. But if you use [Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/features/storage-explorer/), you have the option of selecting encoding like below.

When I used `await QueueClient.SendMessageAsync("Demo")`:
[image]
[image]

But **you do have the option of sending it in Base64** like below so that Azure portal shows it correctly and also to retain same behavior as older package `WindowsAzure.Storage`.

So when I used below code, portal shows correctly:

`await QueueClient.SendMessageAsync(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Demo")))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following on from krishg's answer...

Using that library and version (12.4.2), I can add 65,500 string characters (NB all chars <= ASCII 127) as follows: `SendQueueMessage(new string('a', 65500))`

The SDK/library converts this to UTF8 bytes and stores that (hence the mention of ASCII values).

In Azure Storage Explorer, if the every character is a valid base64 character, & the message length is divisible by 4, then the message is displayed in the list with base64 decoding chosen by default.

Also when the message is opened, the Base64 option is selected first.  You can switch to UTF8 manually, as krishg states.